How to prevent Elliptical Path Reorientation of SMAC Planner in Nav2 Ackermann Robot
Hi I am using ROS2 Iron and NavigateTroughPoses behavior to navigate over GPS waypoints. The global path planner configured is the SMAC Planner set for a Dubin motion model. I am encountering unwanted elliptical paths when the planner tries to reorient my nonholonomic truck. This behavior occurs as the planner attempts to align the truck to avoid obstacles. However, I would prefer the planner look for a "Forward Cone Projection path which strictly avoids ellipses.
Desired Behavior:

Current Behavior:


Attempts

Increased non_straight_penalty and cost_penalty do discourage curvy paths, but it only reduced options without eliminating elliptical orientation recovery.
Modified ange_quantization_bins hoping to limit lateral expansions but the issue persists.
Adjusted analytic_expansion_ration and analytic_expansion_max_cost aiming for fewer path iterations, yet the planner still defaults to these ellipses.
Tuned the MPPI controller to follow the path very aligned in xy and orientation, also set it to prefer forward direction, and avoid lateral expansions, penalized direction change etc...

Question
What adjustments can I perform in SMAC Planner or the overall Nav2 setup (BT?) to encourage straighter or even curvy (but forward paths) and avoid these sort of reorientation maneuvers?
My nav2 configuration file can be checked on this link: nav2_params.yaml
